# Branch Cuts, Differentitate $Log(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, branch-cuts

I'm struggling to understand the theory behind branch cuts; what are they, why do we do them, etc. The following problem is directly from my homework.

> Find the derivative of $f(z) = Log(z)$, recall that the constraint must be written, and determine $Log[f'(−i)]$.

So, I guess, my first question is regarding log vs. Log. I understand the point of the principal value, but how does it apply to the log function?

Secondly, the solution to this problem states that the constraint is $-i = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}}$. I understand how to get from $-i$ to $e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}}$, but I don't understand why this branch cut was chosen.

I can perform the derivative and solve for $f'(-i)$ parts easy enough. I'm just unsure of the work involving the constraints (which I'm assuming is the branch cut).

Thank you.

Comment: For $z \ne 0$ let $f(z) = \ln |z|+ i\text{arg}(\frac{z}{|z|})$. Choosing $\text{arg}$ correctly, you get that $f$ is continuous on $U=\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$. Since $\exp(f(z)) = z$  on $U$, it means automatically that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $f'(z) = \frac{1}{z}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite follow. I've seen the equation $\log(z)=\ln(|z|)+\arg(\frac{z}{|z|})$ before, but I do not understand where it comes from. 

What constitutes a correctly chosen $\arg$?

Comment: For every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ : $\text{arg}(e^{it}) = t + 2k(t) \pi$ for some $k(t) \in \mathbb{Z}$. But $\text{arg}(e^{it}) = t$ is possible only locally, for $t \in [-\pi,\pi)$ or $t \in [0,2\pi)$ or .... Depending which branch you  are considering.

Comment: I understand that you change the domain to restrict a number of solutions from infinite to one. That's easy enough. But I'm not seeing the connection between this and my initial question.

Comment: You didn't say how you defined $\log(z)$. Here I have implicitly defined all the branches of $\log$.

Comment: To answer the question about why we do them, it is because holomorphic => continuous, but for many functions, looking at values as you go around some loop, things are not continuous. Consider just the function $\theta: \mathbb{C} \to [0,2\pi)$. This function is continuous almost everywhere, but when you around a full circle you jump back to $0$. So we cut out a line from the complex plane so that the function can be continuous everywhere. Same idea with log, square root etc.