# Conceptualizing Branch Cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I'm having some trouble grasping the concept of branch cuts. I'm working on the following homework problem.

> Consider $f(z)=\ln(z)$.  Take the branch cut along the negative imaginary axis and determine where $f(-1)=3\pi$

I understand there are a few different choices when making branch cuts, but I'll work off the one my professor chose in his solution.

Firstly, we let $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $\frac{-3\pi}{2}<\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Why do we choose this specific domain? I understand that the natural log function is discontinuous along the negative imaginary axis, but I'm having some trouble visualizing how constricting $\theta$ to this domain helps with the problem.

I think my second question will be answered with a proper explanation of my first, but I'll ask it anyway. When applying the prescribed value $f(-1)=3\pi$, we use the identity $-1=1*\exp(-\pi i)$. My question is regarding the negative value of $\pi$, why does the domain restriction in my first question give us that the angle is $-\pi$ instead of $\pi$?

Rolling with $-\pi$, we get that $$ f(-1)=\ln(1)+i(-\pi+2\pi k) \ \ \forall \ k \in \mathbb N \\ \text{Letting} \ k=2, \ f(-1)= i(-\pi+4\pi)=-3\pi i$$
Is there something I missed? Why does my answer give $f(-1)=3\pi i$ rather than $f(-1)=3\pi$? Does it have to do with the choice of branch cut?

Thank you.

Comment: You asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308593/branch-cuts-differentitate-logz) yesterday. Can you define explicitly two different branches of $\log z$ ? The principal branch is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ and $\log(1)=0$. Can you define it explicitly ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't.

Comment: The principal branch is $\log(r e^{i \theta}) = \ln r + i \theta$ if $r > 0$ and $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi)$. As I said, since $f(z) =\log (z)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ and with $g(z) = \exp(z)$ we have $g(f(z)) = z$ then $f'(z) = \frac{1}{g'(f(z))} = \frac{1}{z}$ so that $f$ is holomorphic and hence analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see a connection between your explanation and my question. If you have the time, could you answer each of my questions individually? That might help me understand what's going on.

Comment: You can also start from $\log(z) = \int_1^z \frac{1}{s}ds$, and the branch will depend on the path of integration $1 \to z$

Comment: Do you understand everything I wrote ? Can you modify it to obtain a different branch ? For example what happens when looking at $\log(z)+2i\pi$ where $\log$ is defined as above

Comment: I'm away from my computer at the moment, so all I see is code. I'll see if I can make sense of it when I get home. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @user1952009, branches would occur every $2\pi$. So, $\theta \in [\pi,2\pi)$, $\theta \in [2\pi , 3\pi)$, etc.

Comment: This is not clear and rigorous enough. Two examples of other branches are : $\log(r e^{i \theta}) = \ln r + i \theta$ if $r > 0$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ which (with the same argument as above) is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$ with derivative $1/z$, and $\log(r e^{i \theta}) = \ln r + i \theta$ if $r > 0$ and $\theta\in [\pi,3\pi)$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ with derivative $1/z$.

Comment: There are also branches of $\log$ being analytic on some weird regions, for example the branch of $\log$ analytic on $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -x+i x^2, x \ge 0\}$ such that $\log(1) = 2i\pi$ and $\log'(z) = \frac{1}{z}$. Since $U$ is simply connected and we have given the derivative and the value of $\log(1)$, the function is defined uniquely by $\log(z) = \log(1)+\int_1^z \log'(s)ds$ where $\int_1^z$ means integrating on any path $1 \to z$ on $U$.

Comment: This still makes no sense to me, do you happen to know a good reference that clearly defines what a branch cut is and how to use it?

Comment: Make some efforts, read again your course and what I wrote. What do you not understand ? The branch cut in those examples is $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0]$ or $\{ -x+i x^2, x \ge 0\}$. The reference is google, wikipedia, MSE, any complex analysis course...